# How do I pass a function with non-static arguments to another function as a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arguments

Here is some sample code:

```
function DoStuff()
{
    var v1 = $('#htmlControl1').val();
    var v2 = $('#htmlControl2').val();

    myFunction1(v1, v2, (myFunction2(v1, v2, myFunction3)));
}

function myFunction1(v1, v2, completeFunc1)
{
    //ajax code here, using jQuery, that calls
    //'completeFunc1' in the 'complete:' block
}

function myFunction2(v1, v2, completeFunc2)
{
    //ajax code here, using jQuery, that calls
    //'completeFunc2' in the 'complete:' block
}

function myFunction3()
{
    //performs some other tasks
}
```

The intent is that `myFunction1` will be called, the ajax call will be made, and, on completion will call `myFunction2` which will in turn do the same thing calling `myFunction3` on its completion.

The actual result is that `myFunction2` is called first, executes `myFunction3` on completion, and returns `null`. `myFunction1` is then called with `null` as its argument for the complete function, resulting in no action on it's completion (I have null checking in there, so that is not an issue).

So, how do I do what I am intending here? How do I properly pass `myFunction2(v1, v2, myFunction3)`, with the given variables, to `myFunction1` as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fancy new JavaScript environments and various libraries (Prototype, Functional) provide a "bind" API that, given a function ("f") and some parameters, returns you a function that, when called, will call "f" with your chosen `this` value and your chosen parameters:

```
var bound = myFunction.bind(something, v1, v2, myFunction3);
```

Now, calling

```
bound();
```

will be exactly like

```
myFunction.call(something, v1, v2, myFunction3);
```

Sometimes people call this "currying", but it's really not true currying because the values are all bound at the time "bind()" is invoked.  Still, it's useful and neat. Depending on how fancy you want to get, "bind()" is pretty easy to implement; I recommend looking at the [Functional.js source code](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/functional-1.0.2.tgz) and going from there. The jQuery version is called `$.proxy()` but it's relatively lame (can't bind arguments).

Comment: I don't know why jQuery doesn't have this. They don't really believe in a Function.bind that lets you bind arguments and the context for a callback. They would just rather you create infinitely deep closures.

Comment: @Juan Mendes there's "$.proxy()" but it's not really as nice.

Comment: Yeah, it only lets you set the context, not the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If you're needing this to be a little more dynamic instead of having the functions hard-coded, how about placing the function references in an Array as the 3rd argument. Then each call could `.shift()` one off the Array, until there are none left.

```
function DoStuff() {
    var v1 = $('#htmlControl1').val();
    var v2 = $('#htmlControl2').val();

    // Array of subsequent functions----v
    myFunction1(v1, v2, [myFunction2,myFunction3] );
}

function myFunction1(v1, v2, funcs) {
    $.ajax({url:'something',
           complete:function() {
               var func = funcs.shift();  // shift it off the Array
               if( func )
                   func(v1, v2, funcs);   // If there was a function, call it
           }                              //   and pass on the arguments.
    });
}

function myFunction2(v1, v2, funcs) {
    $.ajax({url:'something',
           complete:function() {
               var func = funcs.shift();  // shift it off the Array
               if( func )
                   func(v1, v2, funcs);   // If there was a function, call it
           }                              //   and pass on the arguments.
    });
}

function myFunction3() {
    // Performs some other tasks
}
```